# Does anyone know how to retrieve a password for limechat?

Tags: passwords, irc

I am new to using Limechat for irc, and can not find my original password. I tried checking the site resend or create a new one, yet this was not an option on the site. Apparently you need a password when adding a new channel.

Comment: Wrong site to ask brah

Comment: What site do you recommend to ask?

Comment: I found out that generally you do not need a password when adding a channel on limechat. Though you might be prompted for a password, you can enter password in the field when adding a channel, yet it's optional, and rarely needed.

Answer (score 4):

Just for everybody else that have the same issue, the password is on the keychain.

Open it in OSX, search for LimeChat, click on "View Password" and enter your user password. It will display the password right away.